# How to convert data array to show easy to understand results

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

I tried to make a algorithm using Teachable Machine to receive a picture and see if it fall under one of two categories of pictures (e.g dogs or humans), but after I exported the code that was given I couldn't make sense of how I could make the results that were given via array to turn into something that anyone can understand. So far it only shows a list of two numbers (e.g [[0.00058185 0.99941814]] the first number being dogs and the second one humans) I wanted to make it to show which one of the two numbers means dog and human and the percentage of both or to make it to only shows which one is the most probable to be.
Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow.keras
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('keras_model.h5')

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('test_photo.jpg')

#resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
#resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# display the resized image
image.show()

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: Aren't the values probabilities of that data point being class 0 or class 1 ? So given `[[0.00058185 0.99941814]]` that data point is very likely class 1 (that is a human in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Using argmax and max does what you want:

```
"Prediction is {} with {}% probability".format(["dog", "human"][np.argmax(prediction)], round(np.max(prediction)*100,2))

'Prediction is human with 99.94% probability'
```